# Debian and Certbot: where does the package install the cron job?

Tags: debian, package-management, cron, certbot

I installed the python-certbot-apache package per the instructions on certbot.eff.org but can't find any entry for the cron job its supposed to set up.

> The Certbot packages on your system come with a cron job that will renew your certificates automatically before they expire. Since Let's Encrypt certificates last for 90 days, it's highly advisable to take advantage of this feature. 
>   *From: https://certbot.eff.org/#debianjessie-apache*

Where do I find this cron job? I've tried 'crontab -l', with and without sudo both, with no luck.

I understand how to run the cron job to renew the cert; my question is: where is the cron job that this package installed? Did it install?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In any Debian derivate, to list the files installed for a package you usually do `dpkg -L`.

So in your case:

```
dpkg -L python-certbot-apache
```

This is give you the list of *all* files installed, and where.

You can also request the list of files from packages.debian.org

From https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/python-certbot-apache/filelist

> ```
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache-0.10.2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache-0.10.2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache-0.10.2.egg-info/entry_points.txt
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache-0.10.2.egg-info/requires.txt
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache-0.10.2.egg-info/top_level.txt
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache/__init__.py
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache/augeas_configurator.py
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache/augeas_lens/httpd.aug
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache/centos-options-ssl-apache.conf
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache/constants.py
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache/display_ops.py
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache/obj.py
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache/options-ssl-apache.conf
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache/parser.py
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot_apache/tls_sni_01.py
> /usr/share/doc/python-certbot-apache/changelog.Debian.gz
> /usr/share/doc/python-certbot-apache/copyright
> ```

It appears there is no cron job automatic added for the package.

You also need to install the package `certbot`

```
sudo apt-get install certbot
```

List of files:

```
/etc/cron.d/certbot
/lib/systemd/system/certbot.service
/lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer
/usr/bin/certbot
/usr/bin/letsencrypt
/usr/share/doc/certbot/README.rst.gz
/usr/share/doc/certbot/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/certbot/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/certbot/copyright
/usr/share/man/man1/certbot.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/letsencrypt.1.gz
```

So from this last package, the crontab files installed are actually `/etc/cron.d/certbot` for crontab  and you have  `/lib/systemd/system/certbot.service` + `/lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer` for systemd

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've looked through each of the listed txt files with no mention of setting the cron job. Could it be set in one of the listed python files? I'd like to know how to view the cron job that this package installed.

Comment: I've already looked through this with no luck.

Comment: @T.Thomas There is another package. added to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Its actually using systemd.

I used `systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled` to list my running services.

It's named `certbot.timer`